# Invoking Macro by cell click on a generated workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have read various posts on Worksheet functions - **'Worksheet_SelectionChange'**, but my requirement is slightly different. There is a report that I am generating on a new workbook, not the one in which the macro is. In the generated workbook, I want to run a new macro based on a cell selection on a particular column in a particular sheet, i.e.

**Book1** has the macro, which generates a daily report in Book2.

**Book2** has a column which is supposed to ***generate more data based on selection of a cell***.

Please help me in tackling this problem. If there is any other way I should approach this issue, please let me know the same.

Comment: Use a template for workbook 2 which already contains the code and you just paste the new data in.  No need to import bas files, or have the code in book 1 write code in book 2 - just use a template.

Comment: Do you have any code that you can provide that we may assist with? Keep in my we do no provide code for you but will help you with issues you may be having with already existing code. Please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @DarrenBartrup-Cook
When you say template, do you mean that I use a workbook with a working macro in it, and then generate the report and saveAs with the respective date

Comment: @Maldred, Sure I could. But this question is not a code specific. It can be any code, that I want to execute in a generated book, just by clicking a cell in the same.

Comment: Yes, that's just what I mean.  You could even save your template as a macro-enabled-template file (`xltm`) so there's less chance of you accidently overwriting the original file.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :) Would do that